# Can't install any os, boot mode absent

Tags: boot, uefi

I just bought an acer laptop (acer aspire 5 a515-54g-511f) and i have a little issue. It was supposed to come with a linux preinstalled, but after turning it on, it entered directly in efi shell. I tried installing a different os (windows 10 and ubuntu), however, it's not loading from my usb, although it clearly detects it. I tried different formatting styles (I used rufus, different combinations). I tried accessing it from efi shell, but i am receiving different error messages either my bootx64 is not recognized, either it's missing (although it's not, i checked my usb). 
I tried to change the boot mode, however my bios is not showing any boot mode options, only Secure boot, which is disabled, and UEFI SHELL. 
Is something wrong with my device or is there any solution for my issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: If it did not match the description when you decided to buy it, send it back to the vendor forthwith and insist they either credit your card, or provide a replacement which does meet the conditions of sale tout suite.